# Need an optimal data structure for a Network graph

Tags: c#, performance, memory, data-structures, network-analysis

I plan to implement some Algorithms related to social network.

Algorithms include the measurement of importance and community detection.

For example, Betweenness, Closeness, Authority score, and the PageRank. Additionally, some Algorithm for community detection.

Because the data is too big, include more than 100000 nodes and more than 200000 edges, in terms of c# memory issues, I want to apply an effective data structure.

Currently, I am using Jagged array int[][] to store as an adjacency matrix, in which 0 means not connected, x!=0 means these two nodes are connected, the weight of the edge is x.

However, its performance is too bad, too slow.

**Question**: Could anyone give me advice about which data structure will be better than Jagged array int[][] in C#?

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow, i believe you better off to off load the relationship using graph-oriented database (e.g. [JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/)) instead of storing 100,000 nodes in memory manually. take my advice with grain and salt.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have written all algorithm in C# based on the sample data, which is smaller than this final data.

Comment: Graph with 100000 nodes and more than 200000 edges can handle in less then 1GB memory. If your graph will not grow 10x time or more any graph lib can handle with. (QuickGraph for example)

Comment: What about dictionary structure to solve the sparse matrix. What I mean is to store only edges which weights are non-zero. Use Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>. Which one is better? I tried QuickGraph. As for QuickGraph, I need to detect the neighbor each time. Namely, I prefer to store the neighbor firstly in the dictionary. After that, I can directly use it to retrieve it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure  about c#  , but we can do the same in C++  or JAVA with union-find data structure. It performs well with optimization Api implementation. If can easily find the same on google about union-find algorithmic concept for network items. we can also implement with list, Tree and also with Graph with user defined data types.

Thanks,
Ram